# logstash not able to upload data to elasticsearch even the pipeline started

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I am using elasticsearch 7.1.1 and logstash 7.1.1. I am trying to upload a log file to elastic search using grok filter.

Pipeline is getting started, but data is not getting uploaded.

Here is my config file.

```
input{
    file {
        path => "/home/i-exceed.com/pankaj.kumar/elk/logfiles/bankvisit-dialog-service/bankvisit-dialog-service.10-jun.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

filter{
    grok{
        match => { "message" => "\[%{GREEDYDATA:logLabel}\] %{GREEDYDATA:date} %{GREEDYDATA:time} \[%{GREEDYDATA:threadId}\] \[%{GREEDYDATA:transactionId}\]%{GREEDYDATA:message}"}
    }
}


output{

    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "bankvisit"
        document_type => "bankvisitlog"
        }

}
```

Here the console output, it keeps on looping.

```
[2019-06-14T14:08:02,767][DEBUG][org.logstash.config.ir.CompiledPipeline] Compiled output
 P[output-elasticsearch{"hosts"=>"localhost", "index"=>"bankvisit", "document_type"=>"bankvisitlog"}|[str]pipeline:21:5:
elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "bankvisit"
        document_type => "bankvisitlog"
        }
] 
 into 
 org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.ComputeStepSyntaxElement@3a1579c8
[2019-06-14T14:08:02,975][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2019-06-14T14:08:02,979][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[2019-06-14T14:08:07,131][DEBUG][org.logstash.execution.PeriodicFlush] Pushing flush onto pipeline.
[2019-06-14T14:08:08,004][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2019-06-14T14:08:08,005][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `sincedb_path` instead of `/dev/null`, use `nul` as shown below (mind the ***single*** ***'l'*** in `nul`):

```
sincedb_path => "nul"
```